# Encoding a UUID into a 15 character string in Java

Tags: java

I've seen several questions around here that are similar but none are quite what I need. For reasons that unfortunately cannot be changed, I need to take a java UUID and store it in a 15 character long string. All of the numerical change of base methods that i have found can only reduce it to at best 22 characters, but I think it should be possible to make it shorter than that. Does anyone know how this might could be done? The shorter the string the better. Thanks!

Comment: Java UUID is 128 bits. In base64, that's 128/6 = 21.3 printable characters (which is where your 22 comes from). Even considering 8 bits characters (of which a lot are encoding-dependent or not printable), that's still 16 characters.

Comment: For 128 bit probably 8 `char`s are the minimum, but those are not necessarily represent valid `String`s. So you might need a bit more.

Comment: @njzk2 you're right, just small addition - you can have 8 character string with utf-16, but in bytes it still will be 16 bytes

Comment: @Lashane: not all 16 bytes can be used, as not all combination are valid utf-16 characters. (because of the surrogate pairs)

Comment: You can try http://base91.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Can you add more details? What will you be doing with those strings? How are those UUIDs generated? There is a couple of dirty tricks you could use.

Comment: Unless bit patterns are highly repetitive or known a-priori, we can't encode 128 uniformly distributed bits on 8 bytes. See my answer :)

Comment: @luis.espinal You are assuming that one character = one byte. In UTF-16, it's 16 bits per character (2 bytes).

Comment: I know that (that in UTF-16, a character can take two bytes, it is in my answer.) I'm stating the baseline, that assuming a character per byte (a-la ASCII), it is still impossible to encode it in 15 characters (let alone with UTF-16 encoded characters as prescribed in the JLS.)

Comment: Note that my answer doesn't try to start with a string and change encodings. I cast it to base 16 into a BigInteger. We then have the pure 128-bit number representation. We then can create the characters, ending with 8 UTF-16 characters. Add 7 spaces in front or on the end, and you get 15 characters.

Comment: @dibujaron, are you sure you mean a string of 15 characters? Can the characters also be Chinese or Arabic or Thai characters, or must they be strictly ASCII? The latter is impossible, the former is possible, though not standard.

Answer (score 1):

A UUID consists of 128 bits. That can be stored in a java String of 15 chars, as a java char is 16 bit, containing a UTF-16 char. Not all 16 bit values can be taken, and for higher Unicode values some chars must come in pairs. But we only need 9 bit payload per char (15 chars * 9 bit payload >= 128 bits).

So we can store a 9 bit payload per char, say from U+2000 onwards.

```
public static String uuidToStr15(UUID uuid) {
    long[] longs = new long[2];
    longs[0] = uuid.getLeastSignificantBits();
    longs[1] = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
    System.out.println("uuidToStr15: " + Arrays.toString(longs));

    char[] chars = new char[15];
    // 15 chars x 9 bits payload == 135 >=  128.
    final int bitsPerChar = (128 + chars.length - 1) / chars.length;
    final int char0 = 0x2000;
    long mask = (1L << bitsPerChar) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
        int payload = (int)(longs[0] & mask);
        chars[i] = (char)(char0 + payload);
        longs[0] >>>= bitsPerChar;
        longs[0] |= (longs[1] & mask) << (64 - bitsPerChar);
        longs[1] >>>= bitsPerChar;
    }
    return new String(chars);
}

public static UUID str15ToUuid(String s) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    if (chars.length != 15) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "String should have length 15, not " + chars.length);
    }
    final int bitsPerChar = (128 + chars.length - 1) / chars.length;
    final int char0 = 0x2000;
    long mask = (1L << bitsPerChar) - 1;
    long[] longs = new long[2];
    //for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
    for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        int payload = (int) chars[i];
        if (payload < char0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                     String.format("Char [%d] is wrong; U+%04X",
                         i, payload));
        }
        payload -= char0;
        longs[1] <<= bitsPerChar;
        longs[1] |= (longs[0] >>> (64 - bitsPerChar)) & mask;
        longs[0] <<= bitsPerChar;
        longs[0] |= payload;
    }
    System.out.println("str15ToUuid: " + Arrays.toString(longs));
    return new UUID(longs[1], longs[0]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    System.out.println("UUID; " + uuid.toString());
    String s = uuidToStr15(uuid);
    UUID uuid2 = str15ToUuid(s);
    System.out.println("Success: " + uuid2.equals(uuid));
}
```

Of course these strings are not easy to write down, or typed on a keyboard. For that one would need to be more careful, and pick ranges of Unicode code points.

Also "15 chars" is precisely 30 bytes in UTF-16, but will have a longer physical size in UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

From the Java Language Specification [3.10.5. String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) (pay attention to the part in bold):

> A string literal consists of zero or more characters enclosed in
>   double quotes. Characters may be represented by escape sequences
>   (§3.10.6) - one escape sequence for characters in the range U+0000 to
>   U+FFFF, two escape sequences for the UTF-16 surrogate code units of
>   characters in the range U+010000 to U+10FFFF.
>   See §3.10.6 for the definition of EscapeSequence.
>
> **A string literal is always of type String** (§4.3.3).

Every "character" in a Java String can be a UTF-16 value. Meaning a String of length 15 can be up to 30 bytes.

Perhaps you are thinking that in Java, a character will map to a byte (a 8-bit value). But it is not.

So, instead one would opt to use a byte[] array for encoding instead. In fact, in real life, that is what we do when we want to encode things into 8-bit values (primitive bytes as understood in, say, C's unsigned char.)

But then, let's do some math. By definition, [a UUID is a 128-bit value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). 128-bit value is a sequence of 16 bytes (`128 = 16 * 8`.)

So, there is no way in hell that you can universally encode a UUID into 15 bytes. UUID version 1 through 3 might contain redundant or repetitive values that could be compressed or ignored (assuming the reader can properly discern what those "dropped" values are.)

But once you use UUID v4 and v5, forget it. Those are pretty much a sequence of random values, pretty much uncompressable in the general case.

Basic arithmetic then tell us that we should not try to do that :)

Comment: UTF-16 is 2 bytes per character. Some math shows that 128/16 = 8 character string.

Comment: Where in the OP's question is it mentioned that he wants to have 15 bytes? He wanted a 15-character string.

Comment: If my code makes 8 characters, prepend 7 filler characters and viola. You didn't answer his question correctly, since 128 bits can fit into 8 UTF-16 characters.

Comment: @mbomb007 - 128-bit values **carefully* selected for that purpose can fit in 8 UTF-16 characters. Yay to Captain Obvious. However, you cannot in the general case (which is what will happen with a real UUID with random characters in it, not just "8" characters).

Comment: @RealSkeptic - Reading comprehension. By his question, it is obvious he is trying to manipulate a Java UUID into a 15-character Java string (which is by definition UTF-16 encoded). And you simply can't (nor he shouldn't even if he could.) The reduction of the problem (storing the UUID into 15 UTF-16 characters) into a simpler model using 15 bytes helps discern why this is not possible.

Comment: 'cont. Why is it not (still) not possible? Because, in the general case, most, if not all, characters in a UUID will have uniform distribution (many of which will map to 2-byte UTF-16 characters). That is why the OP observes encoding no better than 22 characters (because many will require 2-byte encoding.) See njzk2's comment right under the OP's question.

Comment: 'cont - The fact that he doesn't state "byte" literally, it is obvious that he/she is conflating "byte" with Java "character". My answer recognizes that by reducing the problem to a simpler model of using bytes and showing why it is not possible to encode into 15 characters (be them 8-bit values or UTF-16 characters.)

Comment: Actually, it's not obvious to me at all. And I will ask the OP about that. What he states is (a) He needs to get it into a 15-character string (I assume, a database field or something like that), and (b) that he looked up known algorithms, and they are not sufficient. To me this merely indicates that he is not aware that the algorithms he used are meant to represent binary as ASCII, not as Java characters.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - "To me this merely indicates that he is not aware that the algorithms he used are meant to represent binary as ASCII, not as Java characters."

Exactly. By your own words, the OP does not seem aware that the algorithms he used **on UTF-16** Java characters are for ASCII (either true 7-bit ASCII or 8-bit ASCII extensions such as ISO 8859-1 or CP-1252.)  He is applying a byte-based algorithm on UTF-16 values (conflating both types.) The OP might be aware, conceptually, that they are not the same. But by accident, in this case, he is treating them as if they were.